# What's wrong with my Arch installation? Randomly bizarre screen output since last upgrade

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, video, chrome

Since my last upgrade of Arch Linux (a month ago perhaps), my screen looks weird.

It happens randomly, and it would become normal with a slight update to the current window.

See this screenshot of chromium browser for example,

[image]

If I scroll up or do anything that "updates" the browser, it would become normal again.

Was it a problem related to X or the chromium browser? Anyone knows that?

Comment: What video card are you using?

Comment: @jasonwryan extra/xf86-video-intel 2.21.15-1 (xorg-drivers xorg) [installed]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should read pacman's output:

```
grep -A7 SNA /var/log/pacman.log 
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] >>> This driver now uses SNA as the default acceleration method. You can
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]     still fall back to UXA if you run into trouble. To do so, save a file
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]     with the following content as /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf :
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]       Section "Device"
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]         Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]         Driver      "intel"
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]         Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
[2013-08-26 14:49] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]       EndSection
```

The [Arch Wiki Intel page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel#Choose_acceleration_method) has a little more detail on the move to SNA as the default acceleration method.

Comment: Ah, I've applied those, see if it works ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Do another `pacman -Syu` and reboot. In the last month, there have been ATI driver updates, at least 3 kernel updates (even for LTS kernel), and I seem to recall some X11 updates. I know that something in X11 changed, and then changed again, I'm not sure what it's due to.